# MVC Method will not add values from database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, qsqlquery

Hello I have a method that looks like this

```
 public int AvailableOSI(Item i)
        {

            List<OffSiteItemDetails> d = ItemDetails.Where(x => x.itemID == i.ID).ToList();
            if (d == null || d.Count < 1)
                return 0;

            return d.Sum(x => x.qty);
        }
```

In the table I have the columns

ID, ItemID, qty, SiteID

My goal is to add the qty together if the ItemID's are the same

For example;

if I have a row that looks like this

```
Id | ItemID | qty | SiteID 
1       2      4       1
```

and a row that looks like this

```
Id | ItemID | qty | SiteID 
2       2      3       2
```

I want my method to return "7"

Currently it just returns the qty value of that particular item. Here is a picture of what I mean

[image: row one]

But I also have another row that looks like this

[image]

As you can see they are the same item but the "available" rows should be the same.

In this case available should equal 8

Here is a look at my sql database table

[image: database table]

Comment: What's the problem with return d.Sum(x => x.qty) ?

Comment: @LajosArpad I updated my question to show what it's currently doing vs what I want it to do

Comment: So you have Item and ItemDetails and you want to sum the qty of ItemDetails of that item?

Comment: @LajosArpad yeah I want the "available" column to equal the sum of "qty"of every row that has the same itemID

Comment: it's not obvious to me either why your code doesn't work as expected. Have you managed to narrow it down: is it the .Sum method that doesn't sum all the lines, or is it the .Where method that doesn't filter them?

Comment: @downernn Hard to tell. Weird why it is only finding one ID though and not all of them

Comment: I just get the feeling that the problem is not with the .Sum method, maybe not with this entire chunk of code at all. You are using .Where on an object ItemDetails, which is not created inside the method you are showing us. You need to use your debugging tools and check that ItemDetails includes all the rows you expect it to include and that .Where returns all the rows you expect it to return.

Comment: @downernn hmm yeah I'm to mvc so not really sure to debug a method that is currently in the model and that isn't really triggered by anything except when the view page is loaded. But I also don't get how anything else could be causing the problem. I added a snapshot picture of my how my database looks just in case that can help clear up confusion just in case you thought I was trying to filter simply by "ID" rather that "itemID"

Comment: I'm pretty sure, if you add a breakpoint on the "if" line, you'll be able to see the contents of both the `d` and the `ItemDetails` objects. Or at least their count property. In any case, I'd start there: figuring out how the debugging tools work.